# What is the meaning of className in react?

Tags: reactjs, classname

Can we use any name instead of "container"? Or else are they in built keywords for specific purpose?

```
import logo from './logo.svg';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
        Hello world!
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: We don't know. Do you have any CSS that targets `.container`?

Comment: In `HTML` elements you use `class` for css class name in `JSX` you use `className` for css class name(`class` would also work in React giving a warning). `container` is the class name u should have in your css file.

Answer (score 1):

"ClassName" is used in react the way "class" would be used in HTML. This is because "class" is a reserved word in javascript.

It sounds like you're asking if there's any built in processing - the answer is no, unless you add those dependencies.
A div with a className of container won't be any different from a div without a className unless you add css for the .container class.